# How would i make an execute bot command in discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot command (.e args) that would allow you to execute any code with a bot command.
How would I do that? I've tried:

```
cmd = message.content.slice(2);
cmd;
```

but it didn't do anything when i try to type in Discord, for example, .e message.channel.send("Hello world!")
How would I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off I want to say that this is a **really bad idea**, and I really hope you **know what you're doing**.

However I have implemented this my self as a CTF (Capture the flag) challenge for my university (to be solved by other students).
You can find the complete [source code here](https://github.com/Olian04/discord-ctf/blob/b2e512db4a9495d00140f51defb0a48218131223/src/index.ts).

Now, first off, you could use `eval(cmd)` but this is a **horrible idéa** as this will expose the server to code injection attacks. So to avoid this we will use a VM (virtual machine). In this case i decided to use the package `vm2`. On top of this i decided i wanted to give access to the file system (for the CTF challange), however giving access to the real FS module would spell disaster, so i decided to use `memfs` to emulate the FS module in memory.

*Note: The following code is written in typescript, which is a super set of javascript.*

```js
// index.ts
import { Client, Message } from 'discord.js';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { vol as mfs} from 'memfs';
import * as path from 'path';
import { VM } from 'vm2';

const fakeFileSystemRoot = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'fake_file_system');

mfs.fromJSON(
  fs.readdirSync(fakeFileSystemRoot)
  .map((fileName) => [fileName, fs.readFileSync(path.join(fakeFileSystemRoot, fileName)).toString('utf8')])
  .reduce((res, [fileName, file]) => ({...res, [fileName]: file}), {}),
);

const secrets = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'secrets.json'));

const client = new Client();

const handleMessage = (message: Message) => {
  if (message.channel.type.toLowerCase() !== 'dm') {
    return;
  }
  if (message.author.bot) {
    return;
  }

  const recursiveCatch = (cb) => {
    try {
      cb();
    } catch (err) {
      recursiveCatch(() => {
        const msg = String(err) || 'error message cannot be empty';
        message.channel.send(msg);
        console.log('Err:', msg);
      });
    }
  };

  recursiveCatch(() => {
    const out = [];
    const vm = new VM({
      eval: false,
      wasm: false,
      timeout: 100,
      sandbox: {
        console: {
          log: (...args: any[]) => out.push(args.map(String).join('')),
          info: (...args: any[]) => out.push(args.map(String).join('')),
          warn: (...args: any[]) => out.push(args.map(String).join('')),
          error: (...args: any[]) => out.push(args.map(String).join('')),
          debug: (...args: any[]) => out.push(args.map(String).join('')),
        },
        fs: {
          readSync: mfs.readSync.bind(mfs),
          readFileSync: mfs.readFileSync.bind(mfs),
          readdirSync: mfs.readdirSync.bind(mfs),
          statSync: mfs.statSync.bind(mfs),
          fstatSync: mfs.fstatSync.bind(mfs),
          lstatSync: mfs.lstatSync.bind(mfs),
        },
      },
    });
    console.log('In:', message.content);
    const returnValue = vm.run(message.content);
    out.push(returnValue);
    const outStr = out.join('\n');
    if (outStr.length > 0) {
      message.channel.send(outStr);
      console.log('Out:', outStr);
    }
  });
};

client.on('ready', () => {
  client.on('message', (message: Message) => handleMessage(message));
  client.on('messageUpdate', (oldMessage, newMessage: Message) => handleMessage(newMessage));
});

client.login(secrets.discord_token)
  .then(() => {
    console.info(`Login successful`);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(`Login failed`);
    throw err;
  });
```